# What is the explanation of Yuki sending e-mail to Naoto?

Tags: over-drive

Naoto boasts about his ability and gives 30 minutes handicap to other players. Then surprisingly Yuki sends a mail to Naoto in which she asks Naoto to stop fooling around.

I'm very confused at this point. I have finished the series and I haven't seen Yuki and Naoto together even once. There is not even another sign about they knew each other. What is the background of this intimate message? Where does they know each other?

[image]
(*Episode 11*)